# Vim delay time between two commands with macros

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is it possible two add delay time between execution of commands while using macros, it's like doing the macro in a slow motion... something like macro_dala = 200ms ...if this is not possible, what about adding a delay command while recording..

Answer (score 0):

It depends from content of macro but in general you cannot achieve that unless you create a tool for us that can parse successfully all vim commands (and why not including mappings, plugins and ... :) just think about it for a while).

In case you insist and want to use it for **SIMPLE & KNOWN** commands, you can make it work by programming a function that will read the register where you hold your macro and then separate each command. After that, make a delay after each execution.